# Cordova/PhoneGap: Querying a remote server

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building an Android multiplayer game using Javascript with Cordova. What is the best way to query a remote server? Is it by using the browser and making ajax requests, or is there a way to do it more "native"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/) which provides a real time connection to the server.
I think this might be useful for gaming like application.

Disclaimer: I do not work for socket.io :-)

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "using the browser"? phonegap application is being run in "browser" (webview actually). Anyway, yes, AJAX requests is what you want to use.